# snapshot script via DigitalOcean

Tags: server, snapshot, digital-ocean

I'm running a Digital Ocean server (4 GB) and I'm trying to enable automatic snapshots using the information found [at Digital Ocean](http://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-digitalocean-snapshots-to-automatically-backup-your-droplets).  This script doesn't appear to be doing anything other than shutting down my droplet, however.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages? I suspect that script has a bit of a race condition and is trying to start the snapshot before the power off is completed. You could try adding a sleep statement after `puts "Powered Off #{droplet_id}"`

Comment: @andrewsomthing                                                                                        no errors. just this:                                                                           root@Air-Test-Environment:~#
Broadcast message from root@Air-Test-Environment
        (unknown) at 18:16 ...

The system is going down for power off NOW!
Connection to 45.55.85.31 closed by remote host.
Connection to 45.55.85.31 closed.

Comment: Are you running it on the Droplet itself? You need to run it somewhere else. In order to snapshot a Droplet, it is powered down. So the script can't finish running if you power off the Droplet it is running on.

Comment: oh, that makes way more sense.  Answer the question officially and I'll upvote!

Comment: This might be overkill, but there's [safeharbour buoy] (https://safeharbour.io) which has a snapshot feature, you should be able to set the time the snapshot is done, all in a  GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this tool, much closer to your case. 
Command line, fully automated. Multi-threaded.

I'm author, questions are welcome.

[DoSnapshot](https://github.com/merqlove/do_snapshot)

Answer (score 1):

In order to take a snapshot a Droplet, it needs to be powered down first.  [The script that you linked to](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-digitalocean-snapshots-to-automatically-backup-your-droplets#automate-snapshot-backups-using-a-script) makes an API call to do that. So you can not run the script from the Droplet itself or it will not complete.

You can see how it does it in this function:

```
def power_off(droplet_id)
  url = $baseUrl + "droplets/#{droplet_id}/actions"
  params = {'type' => 'power_off'}
  post(url, params)
end
```